# Print certain pages only

Tags: vba, office-2010, word-2010

I have the following code which works fine:

```
Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Copies:=2
```

This prints my 10 page document twice.

I now want to use the `pages` option to specify only certain pages to print out:

```
Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Copies:=2, Pages:="2, 6-10"
```

I was expecting it to print out pages 2 and 6 to 10 twice, i.e. 2,6,7,8,9,10,2,6,7,8,9,10, but instead it just printed all 10 pages twice.

I am using VBA in Word 2010.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

**RESOURCES:**

From [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff840681%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

> **Pages** - Optional - Variant - The page numbers and page ranges to be
> printed, separated by commas. For example, "2, 6-10" prints page 2 and
> pages 6 through 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages` needs to be added along with `Pages`.

For example:

```
Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Copies:=2, Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Pages:="2,6-10"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution from [the website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840681%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

> expression **.PrintOut(Background, Append, Range, OutputFileName, From,
>   To, Item, Copies, Pages, PageType, PrintToFile, Collate, FileName,
>   ActivePrinterMacGX, ManualDuplexPrint, PrintZoomColumn, PrintZoomRow,
>   PrintZoomPaperWidth, PrintZoomPaperHeight**

You can use `From:="2", To:="5"`.

Comment: According to the link I posted, `Pages` also exists, which should allow me to type in `2, 6-10`?

Comment: Does it work if you try it this way though? Try changing `Pages` to `Range` too.

Comment: Yes, the options `From` and `To` work fine, but that will only allow me to print out a sequence, i.e. pages 2 to 5.  I want more control, i.e. print pages 2 and 6 to 10.

Comment: Try changing `Copies:=2` `to Copies:="2"`

Comment: Also, try swapping `Copies` and `Pages` around (in terms of order).

Comment: Just tried all those suggestions, and it made no difference, each time, it printed all 10 pages twice.

Comment: Found the solution.  Thanks for the help.