# Print custom and current page?

Tags: vb.net, printing, ms-word, vb.net-2010

I am following this [Edraw Link](https://www.edrawsoft.com/embed-word-vbnet.php).

I was able to search for one of my problem using this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661732/print-certain-pages-only).

My code now is

```
  With AxEDOffice1
     .PrintOut(EDOfficeLib.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintRangeOfPages, 1, 1, "", 2)
           // from page , to page , (Page as Object) this one is don't know how to use, number of copies //
  End With

 //This one is for next page but its not working. I print preview first and click a button using code below.
 With AxEDOffice1
        .SlideGotoNext()
    End With
```

My question

1. if I set the range of the page to be print can I `Print Preview it?`
2. How to print current page? (I see this code `.PrintOut(EDOfficeLib.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintCurrentPage)`) but the problem is how to navigate to next / previous pages.
3. How to jump into a specific page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edraw library is built using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word** Library so PrintOut Method is the same as found [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.printout.aspx) (*MSDN article above is very useful to your case*)

*Side Note: To get more attention don't ask anymore about Edraw when things can be done when asking on Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word because it is used by a wide range of people And supported by microsoft.*

- Use `AxEDOffice1.ActiveDocument.PrintOut` Method
- To specify Print range you have to select `EDOfficeLib.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintFromTo` option and specify `From` and `To` parameter. (*Begin page and end page*)

These reference will help you also:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9f0ke7y.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1x2ca5h.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.goto.aspx

Hope i helps

Comment: Thanks. My current problem now is how to jump to a specific page and the number 1 from my question.

Comment: @Kira don't ask anymore about `Edraw` library because you will not be answered. To get more attention ask about `Interop.Word` because it is used by a wide range of people And supported by microsoft.

Comment: @Kira  i will search for your issues. Hope i can help

Comment: Okay I will. Thanks.

Comment: @Kira i am really sorry i didn't find a solution for your issues. Maybe openning asking a new question (on Interop.Word) could get more attention. and a more detailed answer from an expert. Thx for accepting my answer even that i doesn't deserve it

Comment: can you give me a link for `Interop.Word`?